# Python fastKDE beyond limits of data points

Tags: python, kernel-density

I'm trying to use the fastKDE package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastkde/1.0.8) to find the KDE of a point in a 2D plot. However, I want to know the KDE beyond the limits of the data points, and cannot figure out how to do this.

Using the code listed on the site linked above;

```
#!python

import numpy as np
from fastkde import fastKDE
import pylab as PP

#Generate two random variables dataset (representing 100000 pairs of datapoints)
N = 2e5
var1 = 50*np.random.normal(size=N) + 0.1
var2 = 0.01*np.random.normal(size=N) - 300

#Do the self-consistent density estimate
myPDF,axes = fastKDE.pdf(var1,var2)

#Extract the axes from the axis list
v1,v2 = axes

#Plot contours of the PDF should be a set of concentric ellipsoids centered on
#(0.1, -300) Comparitively, the y axis range should be tiny and the x axis range
#should be large
PP.contour(v1,v2,myPDF)
PP.show()
```

I'm able to find the KDE for any point within the limits of the data, but how do I find the KDE for say the point (0,300), without having to include it into var1 and var2. I don't want the KDE to be calculated with this data point, I want to know the KDE at that point.

I guess what I really want to be able to do is give the fastKDE a histogram of the data, so that I can set its axes myself. I just don't know if this is possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I, too, have been experimenting with this code and have run into the same issues. What I've done (in lieu of a good N-D extrapolator) is to build a KDTree (with scipy.spatial) from the grid points that fastKDE returns and find the nearest grid point to the point I was to evaluate. I then lookup the corresponding pdf value at that point (it should be small near the edge of the pdf grid if not identically zero) and assign that value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while searching for a solution of this problem. Similiar to the building of a KDTree you could just calculate your stepsize in every griddimension, and then get the index of your query point by just subtracting the point value with the beginning of your axis and divide by the stepsize of that dimension, finally round it off, turn it to integer and voila. So for example in 1D:

```
def fastkde_test(test_x):
    kde, axes = fastKDE.pdf(test_x, numPoints=num_p)
    x_step = (max(axes)-min(axes)) / len(axes)
    x_ind = np.int32(np.round((test_x-min(axes)) / x_step))
    return kde[x_ind]
```

where `test_x` in this case is both the set for defining the KDE and the query set. Doing it this way is marginally faster by a factor of 10 in my case (at least in 1D, higher dimensions not yet tested) and does basically the same thing as the KDTree query.

I hope this helps anyone coming across this problem in the future, as I just did.

Edit: if your querying points outside of the range over which the KDE was calculated this method of course can only give you the same result as the KDTree query, namely the corresponding border of your KDE-grid. You would however have to hardcode this by cutting the resulting `x_ind` at the highest index, i.e. `len(axes)-1'.